# how to convert slist 'node_ptr' to my own node type

Tags: c++, boost, intrusive-containers

I've declared the following `node` which inherits from `boost::intrusive::slist_base_hook<>` :

```
class InputBufferSglNode : public boost::intrusive::slist_base_hook<>
```

declaration of the list which contains these nodes :

```
class InputBufferSglList : public boost::intrusive::slist<InputBufferSglNode, boost::intrusive::cache_last<true>>
```

I want to get the root node from `InputBufferSglList` member function, so I tried to do :
`InputBufferSglNode* node = this->get_root_node();`
but I get an error :

```
error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'InputBufferSglNode *' with an rvalue of type 'node_ptr' (aka 'boost::intrusive::slist_node<void *> *')
```

Should I cast `node_ptr` to `InputBufferSglNode*` ? which casting should it be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_root_node` is not part of the documented API.

Are you looking for

```
InputBufferSglNode& node = *this->begin();
```

In case you're interested in the reverse:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/intrusive/obtaining_iterators_from_values.html

---

**UPDATE**:

I've read some more in the documentation, and there is a way in which you can do what you want, by using the derived value_traits for your list type:

```
InputBufferSglNode* node = 
      InputBufferSglList::value_traits::to_value_ptr(list.get_root_node());
```

This uses the **[ValueTraits interface](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/intrusive/value_traits.html#intrusive.value_traits.value_traits_interface)** that underlies all intrusive containers.

For all usual node default hooks it will result in a bit of offset arithmetic (to get from the member address to the node address, e.g.). But in practice it might involved casts up and down the class hierarchical (especially when virtual base(s) are involved).

For any [trivial_value_traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/intrusive/trivial_value_traits.html) both `to_value_ptr` and `to_node_ptr` would be the identity function.

Comment: I've found the direct answer to your question, see under **UPDATE**

Comment: Thank you @sehe, this is exactly what i was looking for, I knew about the iterator, but since I need to check 'root' and pop under certain conditions, using iterator would be a bit too much, also notice, `begin()` returns temp value, so it cannot be assigned to reference value as you mentioned in the first code line. (for so others won't get it wrong)

Comment: @SagiLow Oh hah. `begin()` may return a temp, but `*begin()` isn't :) If you prefer you can make it `InputBufferSglNode* node = &*this->begin();` o.O

Comment: It's not actually. `&*iterator` is a fairly common pattern to translate from iterators to reference/pointers. (E.g. `call_some_foo(&string1[0], string1.length())`)